# Can't keep dynamically allocated memory consistent after return

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, recursion, garbage-collection

I'm working on a chess-playing program.  As part of it, I wrote a static method that is supposed to recursively operate on its input by calling itself with varied versions of the board, a **Piece * board[8][8]**, and pass back the the location of the "best" version of the board inside a **std::unique_ptr**, which is the return type of the method.

Node is defined as such:

```
class node
{
    public:
    node();
    ~node();
    std::unique_ptr<node> l;
    std::unique_ptr<node> r;
    std::unique_ptr<node> m;
    node * best;
    int bestval;

    Piece * (*board)[8];
};
```

The goal is to eventually have the result of the initial call to the recursive method contain a "best" value which links to the whole chain of best path choices through the chessboard.  I would then draw the series of board states that result.

As part of this, the board must be preserved.  Whichever board "wins" at each recursive step gets copied to dynamic memory, and the board pointer of the return ( **Piece * (*board)[8]** in the **node** declaration) is set to this dynamically allocated memory.

This is done like so:

```
    std::unique_ptr<node> ret (new node);
    Piece *** reboard = new Piece**[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        reboard[i] = new Piece*[8];
    }
    ...code to copy values to reboard and set other ret property values...
    ret->board = reboard;
    return ret;
```

All the local values of the winning chess board are then copied to reboard.  This all works fine.  If I copy all the values of reboard to a global board at this stage, return, and directly draw that global board to the screen, it draws the correct result.  Likewise, if I set **ret->board** to point to that global board and then copy values to the global board and return, it draws the correct values.

But, if I do what I've written above and try to draw **ret->board**, I get invalid memory access errors in my draw method, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to pin this problem down.  It seems that immediately after return, the memory pointed to by **reboard** is reclaimed somehow.  In this memory which should only be data, I see that entries into the array appear to point to code in msctf.dll, among other invalid data pointers.  I thought it was being reclaimed by garbage collection, so I've even tried putting in some **std::declare_reachable** calls on any and every pointer I can see, but this has not helped.

Anyone notice recognize what's going on here?  Shouldn't that dynamically allocated memory stick around until I free it?

Comment: Look into bitboards; they are better than your data structure. Also, there should be very little heap in chess engine code. I only use heap allocations for the transposition table and during thread setup. Walking up and down the game tree does not require heap allocations-- everything should be preallocated.

Answer (score 0):

> std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that retains sole ownership of an object through a pointer and destroys that object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope. No two unique_ptr instances can manage the same object.

Source: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

In other words, you are freeing the memory as soon as you hit `return`, and then return garbage. Of course it'll cause an access violation to try to dereference that memory.

Comment: There's a global reference to the return pointer of the initial recursive call, and all subsequent calls hold onto the return pointer of their callee, so the unique pointers are indeed sticking around as intended.  I intended to demonstrate this by stating that pointing ret->board to a global board worked fine.

Comment: I'll say it again, in small words: the memory gets freed when `ret` goes out of scope. Quit arguing and use the right smart pointer class if the semantics of `unique_ptr` aren't right for you. In particular if you want to share it (and you do), use `shared_ptr`.